Validar si un carácter ingresado es un número o una letra en LPP
Tengo este pseudocódigo en LPP que pretende determinar si el valor ingresado por el usuario es un número o una letra (FALSO / VERDADERO). El programa no reconoce ningún número que se le ingrese
    entero nNumero
    cadena[100] cNumero
    booleano lNumero
    entero i
    
inicio
    
    Repita
        Escriba "Introduzca un n£mero: "
        lea cNumero
        lNumero <- verdadero
        Para i <- 0 hasta Longitud(cNumero) - 1 Haga
            Si ((cNumero[i] < '0') o (cNumero[i] > '9')) Entonces
                lNumero <- Falso
            Fin Si
        Fin Para
        Si no lNumero Entonces
            Escriba "ERROR: El valor introducido no es un n£mero"
            llamar nueva_linea
        Fin Si
    Hasta lNumero
    
    Escriba "El n£mero introducido es: ", nNumero
    
Fin


El principal problema está en considerar que en lpp los arreglos, incluyendo las cadenas, empiezan en 0. Pues, empiezan en 1.
Entonces esta línea:
Para i <- 0 hasta Longitud(cNumero) - 1 Haga

se debe ajustar a:
Para i <- 1 hasta Longitud(cNumero) Haga

Finalmente en la línea
Escriba "El número introducido es: ", nNumero

La variable nNumero no se está utilizando. En vez de nNumero debería ser cNumero.
